# Jquery: highlight navig of current anchor tag

Tags: jquery, navigation, highlight, jquery-waypoints

i am getting confused and not able to put things together...

- i created a single page website with different sections,
- i made a sticky nav with jquery.sticky.js,
- i highlighted the current tab with the help of this : http://jsfiddle.net/joshnh/YxRqp/.

But the nav tabs do not change the highlight with scolling when i go from one section to another...

I red on internet that Waypoints, a jquery plugin (http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/) can help me but it does not work... can someone tell me what js, css and html codes i must add that it works (with Waypoints or without) ?

## HTML

```
<nav id="mainnav">
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="links">
        <li><a id="homenav" class="scroll" href="#homepage">About</a></li>
        <li><a id="sensnav" class="scroll" href="#parallax1">Sensuality</a></li>
        <li><a id="scennav" class="scroll" href="#parallax2">Scenes</a></li>
        <li><a id="montnav" class="scroll" href="#parallax3">Montage</a></li>
        <li><a id="celenav" class="scroll" href="#parallax4">Celebrities</a></li>
        <li><a id="modenav" class="scroll" href="#parallax5">Mode</a></li>
        <li><a id="portnav" class="scroll" href="#parallax6">Other Portraits</a></li>
        <li><a id="objenav" class="scroll" href="#parallax7">Objects</a></li>
        <li><a id="miscnav" class="scroll" href="#parallax8">Miscellaneous</a></li>
        <li><a id="contnav" class="scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a id="morenav" class="scroll" href="#more">Links & More</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<section id="parallax1">
    <h1>Sensuality</h1>
</section>
```

## JS for the highlight (in the body part of the index.html)

```
<script>
var main = main = $('#mainnav div ul');

$('.scroll').click(function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var full_url = this.href,
        parts = full_url.split('#'),
        trgt = parts[1],
        target_offset = $('#'+trgt).offset(),
        target_top = target_offset.top;

    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:target_top}, 500);

    /* Remove active class on any li when an anchor is clicked */

    $('#mainnav div ul').children().removeClass();

    /* Add active class to clicked anchor's parent li */

    $(this).parent().addClass('active');

});
</script>
```

## CSS

```
nav {
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
position: relative;
z-index: 1000;
background: rgba(26,30,39,0.7);
opacity: 0;
filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}

nav .container {
width: 96%;
}

.links {
height: 50px;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
}

.links li {
height: 50px;
display: inline;
margin: 0 15px 0 0;
padding: 2px;
}

.links a {
font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif;
font-size: 20px;
color: #ffffff;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

.links a:visited {
color: #ffffff;
}

.links a:hover {
color: #b0b825;
}

.links a.current {
color: ffd200;
}

nav#mainnav li.active a { 
color: #ffd200; 
}
```

You can see it live here : http://photography.igorlaszlo.com

Please be precise what i must to do, i am not a professional in javascript...

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

Try this I have made some changes in your code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#top1").parent().addClass('active');
var main = main = $('#main ul');

$('.scroll').click(function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var full_url = this.href,
        parts = full_url.split('#'),
        trgt = parts[1],
        target_offset = $('#'+trgt).offset(),
        target_top = target_offset.top;

    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:target_top}, 500);

    /* Remove active class on any li when an anchor is clicked */

    main.children().removeClass();

    /* Add active class to clicked anchor's parent li */

    $(this).parent().addClass('active');

});

    $(window).scroll(function(event) {
   if($("#top").offset().top < $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).outerHeight()) {
 $("#top1").parent().addClass('active'); 
$("#middle1").parent().removeClass('active'); 
 $("#bottom1").parent().removeClass('active');        
} 
 if($("#middle").offset().top < $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).outerHeight()){
$("#middle1").parent().addClass('active'); 
$("#top1").parent().removeClass('active'); 
 $("#bottom1").parent().removeClass('active'); 
}
 if($("#bottom").offset().top < $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).outerHeight()){
$("#bottom1").parent().addClass('active'); 
  $("#top1").parent().removeClass('active'); 
 $("#middle1").parent().removeClass('active'); 
}       
});
});
```

and in your Html made some changes to the following tags by adding an id attribute

```
        <li><a href="#top" class="scroll" id="top1"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#middle" class="scroll" id="middle1"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#bottom" class="scroll" id="bottom1"></a></li>
```

Here is the working jsfiddle **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YxRqp/284/)**

Hope this helps thank you.

Comment: Thanks a lot... now i must leave but i will check it out this evening !

Comment: Thanks Sarath, i checked out what you suggested. Great, it starts to move ! :) But if you look at it on my website (www.igorlaszlo.com), now, when you click on some menu tabs, others are highlighted, it is a bit messy...

Is there an importance of the order of the tabs add/remove active class ? Or any idea what the problem is ? 

I can not copy the codes here, i do not have enough characters in a comment, if you can be so kind to see it on my website : [www.igorlaszlo.com]

Comment: its not because of the order please tell me in which script file you have appended that code in your webiste.

Comment: I appreciate that you help me ! 
For that code i do not use any attached js file. What i use : 
- http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js 
- http://www.igorlaszlo.com/scripts/main.js
- http://www.igorlaszlo.com/scripts/jquery.sticky.js
- http://www.igorlaszlo.com/scripts/scroll.js
- http://www.igorlaszlo.com/scripts/jquery.parallax-1.1.3.js
- http://www.igorlaszlo.com/scripts/paralax-ini.js
- http://www.igorlaszlo.com/scripts/jquery.easing.min.js
For me the scroll script is suspect...

Comment: When i scroll with the mouse, the highlight arrives when the parallax pictures are still down, but the highlight should change when the parallax pictures arrive on the top of the screen...

Comment: The code what you answered ? Of course i added (with my own class names)... it is not in an attched file but it is on the html page.

Comment: Its because you section size is different and so that the next div comes on the screen.so it effects the calculation set all section to same size

Answer (score 1):

I give an answer for myself and maybe someone will use it too... finally i found a solution which includes : 1) SMOOTH SCROLL to anchor tags (one page website), 2) HIGHLIGHT ACTIVE BUTTON on Navigation and 3) highlight works with mouse wheel scrolling too !

You can find the tutorial here : http://trevordavis.net/blog/jquery-one-page-navigation-plugin and a demo on my webpage here : http://photography.igorlaszlo.com